# How to dynamically load components in Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The path I learned [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader) in the angular docs, is to call createComponent() on a container reference.

Instead of using an input like in the example, I'm importing a component and trying to pass it directly, because [also in the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createcomponent) it says:

> Angular no longer requires component factories to dynamically create components. Use different signature of the createComponent method, which allows passing Component class directly.

But then why my compiler is complaining.
From my understating of the spec, the following is the recommended solution.

```
  loadMore() {
    const viewContainerRef = this.resultArea.viewContainerRef;
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<RecentGridComponent>(RecentGridComponent);
  }
```

But I get

> Argument of type 'typeof RecentGridComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentFactory'.
> Type 'typeof RecentGridComponent' is missing the following properties from type 'ComponentFactory': selector, componentType, ngContentSelectors, inputs, and 2 more.ts(2345)

Instead, I had to instantiate a factory (full code)

```
import { Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RecentGridComponent } from '../recent-grid/recent-grid.component';
import { ResultAreaDirective } from '../result-area.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-filters',
  templateUrl: './search-filters.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-filters.component.sass']
})
export class SearchFiltersComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(ResultAreaDirective) resultArea!: ResultAreaDirective

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loadMore() {
    const viewContainerRef = this.resultArea.viewContainerRef;
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(RecentGridComponent)
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<RecentGridComponent>(factory)
  }

}
```

Comment: The doc you're reading is for v13.0.0, Update your Angular to 13 version and it should solve your issue. Or read doc for 12 version https://v12.angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createcomponent

Comment: You can follow also this: https://github.com/danmt/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by yurzui, the correct spec for v12 is [here](https://v12.angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createcomponent)

To pass the class directly, one should use v13.